# Binary characters returned when reading from socket.getInpitStream()

Tags: java, sockets, docker, character-encoding, java-io

```
package com.examenginedashboard.docker.utils;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import com.examenginedashboard.CONSTANTS.MyValuesConstans; 
import com.examenginedashboard.codePG.service.HttpHijack;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClient;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.command.CreateContainerResponse;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.command.DockerCmdExecFactory;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.command.ExecCreateCmdResponse;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.command.InspectExecResponse;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.model.Bind;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.model.ExposedPort;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.model.Ports;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.model.Volume;
import com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultDockerClientConfig;
import com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientBuilder;
import com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientConfig;
import com.github.dockerjava.core.command.ExecStartResultCallback;
import com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.JerseyDockerCmdExecFactory;

 public class APIBasedCodeCompiler {

    public static void connectToDocker(){
        DockerCmdExecFactory dockerCmdExecFactory = new                                             JerseyDockerCmdExecFactory()
        .withReadTimeout(1000)
        .withConnectTimeout(1000)
        .withMaxTotalConnections(100)
        .withMaxPerRouteConnections(10);
        ExposedPort tcp22 = ExposedPort.tcp(22);
        ExposedPort tcp23 = ExposedPort.tcp(23);


        Ports portBindings = new Ports();
        portBindings.bind(tcp22, Ports.Binding.bindPort(11022));
        portBindings.bind(tcp23, Ports.Binding.bindPort(11023));

DockerClientConfig config = DefaultDockerClientConfig. createDefaultConfigBuilder()
                    .withDockerHost("tcp://127.0.0.1:2375")
                    .build();

        DockerClient docker = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance(config).build();

        Volume volume1 = new Volume("/mydockerbuild"); 
      CreateContainerResponse containerResp = docker.createContainerCmd("busybox")
                .withImage(MyValuesConstans.JAVA_DOCKER)
                .withCmd("sh", "-c", "while :; do sleep 1; done")
                .withAttachStderr(true)
                .withAttachStdout(true)
                .withAttachStdin(true)
                .withVolumes(volume1)
                .withBinds(new Bind("/home/itcostcut/mydockerbuild",volume1))
                .exec();
        String containerId = containerResp.getId();
        docker.startContainerCmd(containerId).exec();
        System.out.println("HOST........... ");
        ByteArrayOutputStream stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stderr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


      final String[] command = {"bash", "-c", "cd mydockerbuild/ && javac NumberToWord.java  && java -cp . NumberToWord exit"};
        ExecCreateCmdResponse execCreateCmdResponse = docker.execCreateCmd(containerId)
                .withAttachStdout(true)
                .withAttachStderr(true)
                .withAttachStdin(true)
                .withCmd(command)
                .exec();
        InspectExecResponse inpect = docker.inspectExecCmd(execCreateCmdResponse.getId()).exec();
        System.out.println("Inspect Info........... "+inpect);
     HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        HttpHijack ws;
        // http://localhost:4243
        //unix:///var/run/docker.sock

            docker.execStartCmd(execCreateCmdResponse.getId()).exec(
                    new ExecStartResultCallback(stdout, stderr));


          System.out.println("Output: "+stdout.toString());
          System.out.println("Error: "+stderr.toString());

        try {
            ws = new HttpHijack(new URI("http://127.0.0.1:2375/v1.27/exec/" + execCreateCmdResponse.getId() + "/start"));
             String payload = "{\"Detach\": false,\"Tty\": false}";
                ws.post(headers, payload);
                String request = "10";
                //Thread.sleep(3000);
                InputStream input = ws.send(request);
                int expectedDataLength=5000;
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(expectedDataLength);
                byte[] chunk = new byte[expectedDataLength];
                int numBytesJustRead;
                while((numBytesJustRead = input.read(chunk)) != -1) {
                    baos.write(chunk, 0, numBytesJustRead);
                }
                System.out.println("Result ............... "+baos.toString());


        } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}
      public static void main(String[] args){   
      connectToDocker();
       }}
```

Below is the HttpHijack.java class which connects to the Java Docker.

```
package com.examenginedashboard.codePG.service;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.net.SocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class HttpHijack {

private static final Logger log =  LoggerFactory.  getLogger(HttpHijack.class);

private URI uri;

private Socket socket;

private boolean handshakeCompleted;

private InputStream chin;

private OutputStream chout;

public HttpHijack(URI url) {
    uri = url;
}

public void post(Map<String, String> headers, String payload) throws java.io.IOException {
    String host = uri.getHost();
    System.out.println("Hostname ........."+host);
    String path = uri.getPath();
    System.out.println("Path..............."+path);
    if (path.equals("")) {
        path = "/";
    }

    String query = uri.getQuery();
    System.out.println("Query................"+query);
    if (query != null) {
        path = path + "?" + query;
    }

    socket = createSocket();
    chout = socket.getOutputStream();
    StringBuffer extraHeaders = new StringBuffer();
    if (headers != null) {
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
            extraHeaders.append(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue() + "\r\n");
        }
    }

    StringBuffer request = new StringBuffer();
    request.append("POST " + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    request.append("Upgrade: tcp\r\n");
    request.append("Connection: Upgrade\r\n");
    request.append("Host: " + host + "\r\n");
    if (headers != null) {
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
            request.append(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue() + "\r\n");
        }
    }

    request.append("Content-Length: " + payload.length() + "\r\n");
    request.append("\r\n");
    request.append(payload);

    chout.write(request.toString().getBytes());
    chout.flush();

    chin = socket.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(chin));
    String header = reader.readLine();
    if (!header.equals("HTTP/1.1 101 UPGRADED")) {
        throw new IOException("Invalid handshake response: " + header);
    }

    do {
        header = reader.readLine();
        log.info("header: {}", header);
    } while (!header.equals(""));

    handshakeCompleted = true;
}

private Socket createSocket() throws java.io.IOException {
    String scheme = uri.getScheme();
    String host = uri.getHost();

    int port = uri.getPort();
    if (port == -1) {
        if (scheme.equals("https")) {
            port = 443;
        } else if (scheme.equals("http")) {
            port = 80;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported scheme");
        }
    }

    if (scheme.equals("https")) {
        SocketFactory factory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        return factory.createSocket(host, port);
    } else {
        return new Socket(host, port);
    }
}

public InputStream send(String command) throws java.io.IOException {
    if (!handshakeCompleted) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Handshake not complete");
    }

    chout.write(command.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    System.out.println("Input Bytes ...... "+command.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    chout.flush();
    // looks like "exit" can't explicitly close the session,
    // shutdown output stream to force close it
    // so that stdout/stderr can be consumed via inputstream
        socket.shutdownOutput();
        System.out.println("Socket String .............. "+socket.toString());

        return socket.getInputStream();

}

public void close() throws java.io.IOException {
    chin.close();
    chout.close();
    socket.close();
}}
```

I will try to explain what I am trying to achieve. In my scenario I am trying to execute some Java program on docker for that i have used Java:7 docker image. 
command = {"bash", "-c", "cd mydockerbuild/ && javac NumberToWord.java  && java -cp . NumberToWord exit"}; is used for running the java code and NumberToWord.java is the java class. we can take any java code to run but it should require some input for execution in my case user input is 10.

The problem is when i am reading the output from socket.getInputStream some of the lines of the out are in binary characters please see the below logs.

```
May 27, 2017 3:46:14 PM com.examenginedashboard.codePG.
 service.HttpHijack  post
  INFO: header: Content-Type: application/vnd.
  docker.raw-stream
  May 27, 2017 3:46:14 PM com.examenginedashboard.
  codePG.service.HttpHijack post
 INFO: header: Connection: Upgrade
 May 27, 2017 3:46:14 PM com.examenginedashboard.
 codePG.service.HttpHijack post
 INFO: header: Upgrade: tcp
  May 27, 2017 3:46:14 PM com.examenginedashboard.
  codePG.service.HttpHijack post
 INFO: header: Api-Version: 1.27
 May 27, 2017 3:46:14 PM com.examenginedashboard.
 codePG.service.HttpHijack post
 INFO: header: Docker-Experimental: false
 May 27, 2017 3:46:14 PM com.examenginedashboard.
  codePG.service.HttpHijack post
 INFO: header: Server: Docker/17.03.1-ce (linux)
  May 27, 2017 3:46:14 PM com.examenginedashboard.
 codePG.service.HttpHijack post
 INFO: header: 
 Input Bytes ...... [B@6436a7db
 Socket String ..............    Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=2375,
  localport=60804]
  Result ...............
```

Output is actually as shown in the image[Final Output Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRKtA.png)

Comment: Please format your code better (indentations can do a lot about readability). In this case it is hard, but please provide us with a working example or at least tell us what the server doing.

Comment: @ThijsSteel  I have edited the Question and tried to explain my scenario. Please take a look. It will be of great help.!!

Comment: I can't quit see the error. I do see some errors, when you write the content length, you take payload.length(), instead it should be the length of the byte array (UTF-8 has variable length)

Comment: What's in the response headers? Maybe the response is zipped? More to the point, why aren't you using `HttpURLConnection`?

Comment: @ThijsSteel thanks for responding.. Expected Output is :                    Your words are here........... !!
Your words are here........... !!
Your words are here........... !!
COME ON LIKE IT !!                                                                                   But if you see the link [Final Output here] above In the first line Result.....[some binary character] is there I am not figure it out why this binary character is appearing is there any encoding mis-match.Thanks again.

Comment: @EJP  Thanks for responding.. you can check the link [Final Ouput here ] for the headers. One thing I noted **header: Content-Type: application/vnd.docker.raw-stream**  is this something causing a problem ? ... I am not using **HttpURLConnection** because i am trying to connect to bash session of docker on which i am running a simple java code which requires input at runtime.I don think i can achieve this with **HttpURLConnection** that's why I am using socket connection.

Comment: Just before you print out the result, you have an expected data length set to 5000, do you really expect this amount of data or is it just a random value? And can you try printing out the numerical value of the array (with Arrays.toString(baos.toByteArray()) ) that might help us find the problem

Comment: @ThijsSteel Thanks for responding..  data length is just a random number i have kept. does  that matter? what length should I keep?. I printed the numeric value as suggested by you. Please find the below array...

Comment: @ThijsSteel Result ............... [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 102, 89, 111, 117, 114, 32, 119, 111, 114, 100, 115, 32, 97, 114, 101, 32, 104, 101, 114, 101, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 32, 33, 33, 10, 89, 111, 117, 114, 32, 119, 111, 114, 100, 115, 32, 97, 114, 101, 32, 104, 101, 114, 101, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 32, 33, 33, 10, 89, 111, 117, 114, 32, 119, 111, 114, 100, 115, 32, 97, 114, 101, 32, 104, 101, 114, 101, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46,

Comment: 46, 46, 32, 33, 33, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 105, 110, 112, 117, 116, 32, 105, 110, 32, 87, 111, 114, 100, 115, 32, 58, 32, 32, 84, 101, 110, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19, 67, 79, 77, 69, 32, 79, 78, 32, 76, 73, 75, 69, 32, 73, 84, 32, 33, 33, 10]

Comment: If you knew the actual length, you could itilize the socket more efficiently, but that doesn't matter much.

Comment: @If we convert the above the by array using ...                                 public void convertByteArrayToString() {
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[] {<bytes array>};
        String value = new String(byteArray);
        System.out.println(value);
    }                                                                                                           we will get the output which has binary character. This might not help just a way to reproduce my issue.

Comment: I don't think this is an encoding problem. "1000000" is just not a normal sequence (even when converted to decimal -> 64 -> @). The strange characters always appear at the end and beginning of a line, maybe they are just sent wrong?

Comment: You also have a BufferedReader, that can give problems (it will read data and put it in its buffer, even when you don't want it to anymore).

Comment: @ThijsSteel is BufferedReader causing the problem?..if yes any alternative to this ?

Comment: @Ajmal Rehman i don't think it's causing this specific problem, but it might be

Comment: @ThijsSteel header: Content-Type: application/vnd.docker.raw-stream is this something to worry about?  while doing handshake the docker  returns the above content type. is there any special handling for this?

Comment: Yes, i thought it was just a raw stream. But it turns out to be something special. I'll try it and send the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the docker raw stream. It multiplexes the `stdoud` and `stderr` into one channel. To do this, before each bit of content, it sends an 8-bit header.

- The first bit is 1 if the following content is for stdout, 2 for stderr and 0 for stdin.
- The second, third and fourth bit are always zero
- The last 4 bits are the length of the content in big endian.

To decode this do the following:

1. Read the header
2. Determine content length
3. Read content (note that even if the content is for stderr and we don't want it, we still need to read it).
4. If the content is actual content, add it to the buffer

The following test does this for the array you provided:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    byte[] data = new byte[] {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 102, 89, 111, 117, 114, 32, 119, 111, 114, 100, 115, 32, 97, 114, 101, 32, 104, 101, 114, 101, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 32, 33, 33, 10, 89, 111, 117, 114, 32, 119, 111, 114, 100, 115, 32, 97, 114, 101, 32, 104, 101, 114, 101, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 32, 33, 33, 10, 89, 111, 117, 114, 32, 119, 111, 114, 100, 115, 32, 97, 114, 101, 32, 104, 101, 114, 101, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46,46, 46, 32, 33, 33, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 105, 110, 112, 117, 116, 32, 105, 110, 32, 87, 111, 114, 100, 115, 32, 58, 32, 32, 84, 101, 110, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19, 67, 79, 77, 69, 32, 79, 78, 32, 76, 73, 75, 69, 32, 73, 84, 32, 33, 33, 10};
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data); //I just created this for testing

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] header = new byte[8];
    while(true){
        if(!readFully(is, header, 8)) break;
        int contentSize = ((header[4] & 0xFF) << 24) | ((header[5] & 0xFF) << 16)
                | ((header[6] & 0xFF) << 8) | (header[7] & 0xFF);
        boolean actualContent = header[0] == 1;
        byte[] content = new byte[contentSize];
        if(!readFully(is, content, contentSize))break;
        if(actualContent)
            baos.write(content, 0, contentSize);
        else
            System.err.println(new String(content));
    }

    System.out.println(baos.toString());


}

/**
 * Read a given number of bytes from the stream and store them in the buffer.
 * 
 * @param   is
 *          The input stream to read from
 * @param   buffer
 *          The buffer to store it in
 * @size    size
 *          The number of bytes to read
 * 
 * @return  True if and only if all bytes were read.
 */
public static boolean readFully(InputStream is, byte[] buffer, int size) throws IOException{
    int totalAmountRead = 0;
    while(totalAmountRead < size){
        int amountJustRead = is.read(buffer, totalAmountRead, size-totalAmountRead);
        if(amountJustRead == -1)
            return false;
        totalAmountRead += amountJustRead;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This gives as output:

```
Your words are here........... !!
Your words are here........... !!
Your words are here........... !!
input in Words :  Ten
COME ON LIKE IT !!
```

Comment: You are Awesome!! Thanks alot it worked like a charm!! i have been working for more than 8 days. I didn't understand the whole thing though.Any refrence doc that i can go through to understand the whole process?.  May be i am trying to be little ambitious, I tried to run another programming language which has the following sequence it didn't work it has the following sequence .....  [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 98, 97, 115, 104, 58, 32, 108, 105, 110, 101, 32, 48, 58, 32, 99, 100, 58, 32, 109, 121, 100, 111, 99, 107, 101, 114, 98, 117, 105, 108, 100, 47, 58, 32, 78,

Comment: 111, 32, 115, 117, 99, 104, 32, 102, 105, 108, 101, 32, 111, 114, 32, 100, 105, 114, 101, 99, 116, 111, 114, 121, 10]

Comment: I didnot understand the line int contentSize = ((header[4] & 0xFF) << 24) | ((header[5] & 0xFF) << 16)
                | ((header[6] & 0xFF) << 8) | (header[7] & 0xFF);                                                            Thanks again for this awesome help.I would like to have your email address.

Comment: For your first question: notice that the first character is a 2, which means that this is an error message. You can also save these if you want

Comment: For your second question: i'll assume you know that an int is stored as 32bit. A byte is 8 bits. What i do in that line is combine all the bytes to an int

Comment: @AjmalRehman just a friendly reminder. If the answer is correct, you might want to accept it.

Comment: Done Thanks again!!